# How can I load php page and show alert by jquery when it is needed?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a site and user can resend the serial by a form submit with calling a php page and shows alert. 
If I don't use jquery, the serial sender page and alert can be shown before DOM's ready and blocks a page's loading.
I would like to combine php and jquery.

When statement 
 `if ( ($_GET["email"]!="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) )`
    
returns true, page should 
process the given data and show an alert.
When statement `if ( ($_GET["email"]=="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) )`
page should show an alert with error message.

kulcsujra.php is responsible for sending mails with requested data.

My code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

          <script>

          $( document ).ready(function() {

        <?php

        if ( ($_GET["email"]!="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) ) 
        {include 'kulcsujra.php';} 

        if ( ($_GET["email"]=="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) ) {"alert('Adjon meg egy e-mail címet!');";}

        ?>


          });

          </script>

    </head>
    <body>


<form action="" method="get">

<div style="width:285px; border:1px solid white;text-align: center;">

<span><font color="white">E-mail cím: </font></span><input type="text" name="email" size="27"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Újraküld" name="submit"/>

</div> 

</form>


</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your code doing now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't echoing your javascript code

change to this:

```
if ( ($_GET["email"]=="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) ) {echo "alert('Adjon meg egy e-mail címet!');";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put echo before your alert string

like this

```
  if ( ($_GET["email"]=="") && (isset($_GET["submit"])) ) {
   echo "alert('Adjon meg egy e-mail címet!');";
}
```

Hope that helps.